# C# WCF Web Api 4 MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-web-api

I am using the WCF Web Api 4.0 framework and am running into the maxReceivedMessageSize has exceeded 65,000 error.

I've updated my webconfig to look like this but because I am uisng the WCF Web Api I think this isn't even used anymore as I am no longer using a webHttpEndpoint?

```
<standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" 
                          helpEnabled="true" 
                          automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
                          maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" />       

      </webHttpEndpoint>
```

**Where do I specify MaxReceivedMessageSize in the new WCF Web Api?**

I've also tried a CustomHttpOperationHandlerFactory to no avail:

```
  public class CustomHttpOperationHandlerFactory: HttpOperationHandlerFactory
    {       
        protected override System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<HttpOperationHandler> OnCreateRequestHandlers(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint, HttpOperationDescription operation)
        {
            var binding = (HttpBinding)endpoint.Binding;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;

            return base.OnCreateRequestHandlers(endpoint, operation);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to do this programatically (via using MapServiceRoute with HttpHostConfiguration.Create) the way you do it is like this:

```
IHttpHostConfigurationBuilder httpHostConfiguration = HttpHostConfiguration.Create(); //And add on whatever configuration details you would normally have

RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<MyService, NoMessageSizeLimitHostConfig>(serviceUri, httpHostConfiguration);
```

The NoMessageSizeLimitHostConfig is an extension of HttpConfigurableServiceHostFactory that looks something like:

```
public class NoMessageSizeLimitHostConfig : HttpConfigurableServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);  

        foreach (var endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            var binding = endpoint.Binding as HttpBinding;    

            if (binding != null)
            {
                binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
            }
        }
        return host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the maxReceivedMessageSize is a property you have to define on the binding you´re using. WCF in .Net 4 introduced the simplified configuration, so if you don´t configure anything, default values will be used.
The example below is valid for the wshttpBinding, you have the ammend it according to your used binding and register it in your web.config (assuming you´re using an IIS hosted service) in the servicemodel-binding section.

```xml
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CalculatorBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" >
      <security mode="Transport" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000"
      maxArrayLength="2000000"
      maxBytesPerRead="2000000"
      maxNameTableCharCount="2000000" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

HTH
Dominik

Comment: Hi nextgenneo, did you manage to get your code running till now?

Answer (score 3):

If you are hosting in IIS, you can set the values where ever you define the route (in my case, the global.asax).  If you have `TransferMode` set to buffered (the default), you will also need to set `MaxBufferSize` to the same value as `MaxReceivedMessageSize`.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   var config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
   config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
   config.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
   RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<MyService>("api", config);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it in code

```
var endpoint = ((HttpEndpoint)host.Description.Endpoints[0]);  //Assuming one endpoint
endpoint.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
endpoint.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10;  // Allow files up to 10MB
```

If you create a your own custom host, derived from the standard one, there is a method that you can overload to configure the HttpEndpoint.

Comment: where do I actually put this code? I don't know where the host is. I tried putting it in my HttpOperationHandlerFactory OnCreateRequestHandlers but only have access to the endpoint.

Comment: @nextgenneo  Ahh, you are not self hosting.   Good point.  Not sure.  I'll let you know if I find out.

Comment: Is there a way to increase this per API or per Controller? I don't want to open up the message size for the whole API?

Comment: @ShawnWildermuth  In the new ASP.NET Web API beta I believe there is currently just one GlobalConfiguration.Configuration so the answer is no.  However, there has been talk of changing this. It would be very easy to use a MessageHandler to add the protection back in.