# ASP.NET Web API - How to alter the maximum amount of items in an XML Object Graph

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api

When returning a large amount of XML data through an ASP.NET Web API service the error: `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)` is produced. This error is usually found when there is a circular dependency in the model but this is not the case here as the data returns perfectly when there is a smaller amount of data.

The error seems to be produced when the amount of nodes surpasses 60,000, after doing some research I found that there is a WCF parameter that limits the amount of items in an object graph, this parameter has a default value of: 65,536 is this what is causing my problem? and if so is there a way in which I can alter that value in ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: Have you found [this article](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/)?  Do you know what specific error is being thrown on the server (that then produced the 500)?

Comment: Yes, but that article refers to files used as input, I am looking to increase the limit of the maximum XML output.

This is essentially the problem I am having: http://forums.asp.net/t/1353779.aspx/1 but the solution posted there is for WCF whereas I am looking to do the same thing in MVC 4 Web API.

Comment: What is the underlying exception?

Comment: This is the only error I get: "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request."

Comment: Are you using the RouteTables.Routes.MapServiceRoute in your global.asax? If yes you can create an instance of the HttpConfiguration before this and then increase the values Ex: var config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
   config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
   config.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

Comment: I am using RouteCollection.MapRoute(), I already have a HttpConfiguration instance but it doesn't have parameters for either 'MaxReceivedMessageSize' or 'MaxBufferSize'.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462571/c-sharp-wcf-web-api-4-maxreceivedmessagesize

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need that much nodes to be returned? Maybe you should consider paging it using $top={pageSize}&$skip={pageNumber} in query.
However I assume you are using [Queryable] attribute in API controller. If so you can try using MaxNodeCount property.